# In Java, what do you call a class with a private constructor or many private constructors?

Tags: java, class, constructor, visibility, private

What would it mean if a class had only private
constructors?

Can you name such a class?

Comment: It could be a singleton, but that's just one example.

Comment: In few particular cases, it means you don't want people to instantiate object of this class so the people can only use the public static members of this class (variables and methods).

Comment: A "homework" class, perhaps?  :)

Answer (score 2):

Constructor can be private for several reasons:
1. Singleton class - could not be instantiated or inherited.
2. Inner class - can be instantiated only by outer class.